# ExtJS -- dynamically generate checkboxes

Tags: extjs

I have a checkbox group which will have a dynamic number of checkboxes. The backend returns data containing the label and the input value. I loop these records and generate a checkbox object for each one. But when I pass the generated array into the items array, nothing happens.

Here are snippets of my checkbox group class.

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.form.field.CheckboxGroup",{
  extend:"Ext.form.CheckBoxGroup",
  ...
  ...
  initComponent:function(){

     this.items = getCheckboxes();

     ...

     this.callParent(arguments);
  },

  getCheckboxes:function(){
     Ext.Ajax.request({
        url:"blah/getcheckboxes",
        scope:this,
        success:function(resp_){
          var resp = Ext.JSON.decode(resp_.responseText);
          var checkboxesArr = [];
          if(resp.data){
            for(var i=0; i<resp.data.length; i++){
              checkboxesArr.push({boxLabel:resp.data[i].label, inputValue:resp.data[i].id, ....});
           }
         }
         return checkboxesArr;
     });

/*return checkboxesArr = [
       {boxLabel: 'Yes', name: this.name, inputValue: 'Y'},
       {boxLabel: 'No', name: this.name, inputValue: 'N'}         
    ];*/
}
```

If I uncomment the static checkboxesArr with the 2 checkboxes and return that instead it works, but it doesnt work with the checkboxesArr generated with the backend response.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ajax call is asynchronous so you can `add` the items instead:

```
getCheckboxes: function () {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: "data1.json",
        scope: this,
        success: function (resp_) {
            var resp = Ext.JSON.decode(resp_.responseText);

            var checkboxesArr = [];

            if (resp.data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < resp.data.length; i++) {
                    checkboxesArr.push({
                        boxLabel: resp.data[i].label,
                        inputValue: resp.data[i].id
                    });
                }
            }
            this.add(checkboxesArr);
        }
    });
}
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1lgc

Comment: Tried with API (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3leh) its working but in project getting as below error in this.add(checkboxesArr). Could you please help on this

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at R.add ()
    at R.success ()
    at Object.callback ()
    at R.onComplete ()
    at R.onStateChange ()
    at app_20220920133708.js?_dc=20220920133708:formatted:13806:19
    at Object.elevate ()
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> ()